# What makes cross domain ajax insecure?

Tags: ajax, security, cross-domain

I'm not sure I understand what types of vulnerabilities this causes.

When I need to access data from an API I have to use ajax to request a PHP file on my own server, and that PHP file accesses the API. What makes this more secure than simply allowing me to hit the API directly with ajax?

For that matter, it looks like using JSONP http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP you can do everything that cross-domain ajax would let you do.

Could someone enlighten me?

Comment: It belongs on http://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the problem that the same-origin policy is trying to solve.

Imagine that I'm logged into Gmail, and that Gmail has a JSON resource, http://mail.google.com/information-about-current-user.js, with information about the logged-in user. This resource is presumably intended to be used by the Gmail user interface, but, if not for the same-origin policy, any site that I visited, and that suspected that I might be a Gmail user, could run an AJAX request to get that resource *as me*, and retrieve information about me, without Gmail being able to do very much about it.

So the same-origin policy is not to protect your PHP page from the third-party site; and it's not to protect someone visiting your PHP page from the third-party site; rather, it's to protect someone visiting your PHP page, and any third-party sites to which they have special access, *from your PHP page*. (The "special access" can be because of cookies, or HTTP AUTH, or an IP address whitelist, or simply being on the right network — perhaps someone works at the NSA and is visiting your site, that doesn't mean you should be able to trigger a data-dump from an NSA internal page.)

JSONP circumvents this in a safe way, by introducing a different limitation: it only works if the resource is JSONP. So if Gmail wants a given JSON resource to be usable by third parties, it can support JSONP for that resource, but if it only wants that resource to be usable by its own user interface, it can support only plain JSON.

Comment: This is a good description of the problem. My misunderstanding was thinking the problem came from what sites other than the one you were on could do to you. The problem is really what the site you are currently visiting can do to you. It makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 2):

Many web services are not built to resist [XSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery), so if a web-site can programmatically load user data via a request that carries cross-domain cookies just by virtue of the user having visited the site, anyone with the ability to run javascript can steal user data.

CORS is a planned secure alternative to XHR that solves the problem by [not carrying credentials  by default](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-credentials-respons).  The CORS spec explains the problem:

> User agents commonly apply same-origin restrictions to network requests. These restrictions prevent a client-side Web application running from one origin from obtaining data retrieved from another origin, and also limit unsafe HTTP requests that can be automatically launched toward destinations that differ from the running application's origin.
>
> In user agents that follow this pattern, network requests typically use ambient authentication and session management information, including HTTP authentication and cookie information.

EDIT:

The problem with just making XHR work cross-domain is that many web services expose [ambient authority](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambient_authority).  Normally that authority is only available to code from the same origin.

This means that a user that trusts a web-site is trusting all the code from that website with their private data.  The user trusts the server they send the data to, and any code loaded by pages served by that server.  When the people behind a website and the libraries it loads are trustworthy, the user's trust is well-placed.

If XHR worked cross-origin, and carried cookies, that ambient authority would be available to code to anyone that can serve code to the user.  The trust decisions that the user previously made may no longer be well-placed.

CORS doesn't inherit these problems because existing services don't expose ambient authority to CORS.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong: It doesn't have to be a XSRF vulnerability if sensitive data is sent back as a response to a perfectly valid HTTP request with correct session cookies and all? Otherwise, basically every website with a login system would be vulnerable to XSRF by your definition.

Comment: So you're saying that the difference between pinging a url with ajax and pinging it with PHP is that the ajax behaves as if it was the user himself visiting that page, and the PHP behaves as if it is the server the PHP is running on visiting that page?

Comment: @NiklasB., I think I agree.  The problem is with ambient authority that is normally only exercisable by code from the same-origin.  XSRF is one kind of abuse of ambient authority, but there are others.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me why there wasn't a flag to prevent credential carrying from the beginning of ajax.

Comment: @Joren, The story I've heard is that XSRF was predicted as a problem by a number of security researchers but was initially dismissed as an attack vector of only theoretical interest.  The folk on `cap-talk@mail.eros-os.org` would probably be able to fill you in on that history if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern of `JS->Server(PHP)->API` makes it possible and not only best, but essential practice to sanity-check what you get while it passes through the server. In addition to that, things like poisened local resolvers (aka DNS Worms) etc. are much less likely on a server, than on some random client.

As for JSONP: This is not a walking stick, but a crutch. IMHO it could be seen as an exploit against a misfeature of the HTML/JS combo, that can't be removed without breaking existing code. Others might think different of this.

While JSONP **allows** you to unreflectedly execute code from somwhere in the bad wide world, nobody **forces** you to do so. Sane implementations of JSONP allways use some sort of hashing etc to verify, that the provider of that code is trustwirthy. Again others might think different.

Answer (score 0):

With cross site scripting you would then have a web page that would be able to pull data from anywhere and then be able to run in the same context as your other data on the page and in theory have access to the cookie and other security information that you would not want access to be given too. Cross site scripting would be very insecure in this respect since you would be able to go to any page and if allowed the script on that page could just load data from anywhere and then start executing bad code hence the reason that it is not allowed.

JSONP on the otherhand allows you to get data in JSON format because you provide the necessary callback that the data is passed into hence it gives you the measure of control in that the data will not be executed by the browser unless the callback function does and exec or tries to execute it. The data will be in a JSON format that you can then do whatever you wish with, however it will not be executed hence it is safer and hence the reason it is allowed.

Comment: But a website can already pull data from anywhere, and run it in the context of the current page. I can put <script src="virus.com/givemeavirus"></script> and the browser will happily run it with full permission. This is where I have confusion.

Comment: But that will not have any access to javascript from another website, hence the security behind cross site scripting.

Comment: I got a very different impression of JSONP than you did upon reading the Wikipedia JSONP article -- what is returned with JSONP requests is explicitly _not_ JSON, but rather arbitrary JavaScript that _often_ includes data in a JSON format in addition to function definitions or executions.

Comment: JSON is returned otherwise why would it be JSON with padding. The JSON is wrapped in the function you want to call and is passed as the arguments.

Comment: @darren102 - You're right. The data we "should" be getting back from a JSONP request is JSON with padding. However, there's nothing preventing the server from responding with arbitrary JavaScript code - which will then be executed in the global context.

Answer (score 0):

The [original XHR](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/NOTE-XMLHttpRequest1-20120117/) was never designed to allow cross-origin requests. The reason was a tangible security vulnerability that is primarily known by [CSRF attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29).

In this attack scenario, a third party site can force a victim’s user agent to send forged but valid and legitimate requests to the origin site. From the origin server perspective, such a forged request is not indiscernible from other requests by that user which were initiated by the origin server’s web pages. The reason for that is because it’s actually the user agent that sends these requests and it would also automatically include any credentials such as cookies, HTTP authentication, and even client-side SSL certificates.

Now such requests can be easily forged: Starting with simple GET requests by using `<img src="…">` through to POST requests by using forms and submitting them automatically. This works as long as it’s predictable how to forge such valid requests.

But this is not the main reason to forbid cross-origin requests for XHR. Because, as shown above, there are ways to forge requests even without XHR and even without JavaScript. No, the main reason that XHR did not allow cross-origin requests is because it would be the JavaScript in the web page of the third party the response would be sent to. So it would not just be possible to send cross-origin requests but also to receive the response that can contain sensitive information that would then be accessible by the JavaScript.

That’s why the original XHR specification did not allow cross-origin requests. But as technology advances, there were reasonable requests for supporting cross-origin requests. That’s why the original XHR specification was extended to [XHR level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) (XHR and XHR level 2 are now merged) where the main extension is to support cross-origin requests under particular requirements that are specified  as [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/). Now the server has the ability to check the origin of a request and is also able to restrict the set of allowed origins as well as the set of allowed HTTP methods and header fields.

Now to JSONP: To get the JSON response of a request in JavaScript and be able to process it, it would either need to be a same-origin request or, in case of a cross-origin request, your server and the user agent would need to support CORS (of which the latter is only supported by modern browsers). But to be able to work with any browser, JSONP was invented that is simply a valid JavaScript function call with the JSON as a parameter that can be loaded as an external JavaScript via `<script>` that, similar to `<img>`, is not restricted to same-origin requests. But as well as any other request, a JSONP request is also vulnerable to CSRF.

So to conclude it from the security point of view:

- XHR is required to make requests for JSON resources to get their responses in JavaScript
- XHR2/CORS is required to make cross-origin requests for JSON resources to get their responses in JavaScript
- JSONP is a workaround to circumvent cross-origin requests with XHR

But also:

- Forging requests is laughable easy, although forging valid and legitimate requests is harder (but often quite easy as well)
- CSRF attacks are a not be underestimated threat, so learn how to [protect against CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)