# How to get 'getJSON' response header

Tags: javascript, rest, jquery

I need to access the size of response message I am getting from another machine (cross-domain request) using $.getJSON, although I can see the request and response in chrome console, it does not work. Here is my request code:

```
xhr=$.getJSON('http://192.168.1.102/server/server.php?callback=?',   
{data:array}, function(res){
alert(xhr.getAllResponseHeader());
}, 
type='json');
```

when running I get "Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'getAllResponseHeader' " error. When I use

```
alert(xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Length"));
```

I get "null".

Please consider that I am using cross-domain get.

Comment: The correct method name is `getAllResponseHeaders`.

Comment: For cross domain, it probably uses JSONP. and their doc says `However, since JSONP and cross-domain GET requests do not use XHR, in those cases the jqXHR and textStatus parameters passed to the success callback are undefined.`

Comment: 1- @Andrei : thanks for "s" you are right, when I alert xhr.getAllResponseHeaders(); it returns nothing, not even null.

Comment: Are you getting something in res?

Comment: @HungryCoder Then what is the solution? Can we count bts by own in javascript and php?

Comment: @FAngel Yes, I am getting a sorted array of numbers sorted using a pHp file.

Comment: As far as I know, cross domain requests are done with `script` tag and it does not provide request headers info, at least I never heard about that. So, I'm afraid you just can't get Content-Length header in case of that request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I observed many visits to this question and thought it is good to provide the solution to this problem. Unfortunately none of the offered solutions worked and I did two things to solve the problem.

1. I verified that I have the following codes right after the `<?php` tag in my server side:

   ```
   header("Content-Type: application/*");
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin :*");
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS");
   header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000");
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");
   ```
2. I slightly changed the way I do the call as follows and it always works for me.

   ```
   function name(){
       $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           crossDomain: true,
           data: {
               data1: data
           },
           dataType: 'text',
           error: function (res, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               alert('Connection Terminated. Please try again');
           },
           success: function(res, textStatus, jqXHR) {
           //Process the result in res;
           },
       });//ajax
   }//function name
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Do not use JSONP, it isn't really a cross domain request ([JSONP explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289789/i-dont-get-how-jsonp-is-any-different-from-ajax)), it's a hack that only works for GET requests, whereas AJAX allows any http method.

Try preparing your server to allow cross domain requests ([more details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)) and doing this:

```
$.ajax({
type: "get",
url: "http://192.168.1.102/server/server.php",
crossDomain: true,
cache: false,
dataType: "json",
contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
data: array,
success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Length"));
},
error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(errorThrown);
}});
```

Thereby, the xhr object is set and you can access it's header.

Comment: thanks vhtc, I will try it soon. Can I do POST using this approach as well? I use Apache Tomcat, is it okay then?

Comment: You can make http requests of any type.

Comment: On the server side, you need to add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to the response.

Comment: thank you very much Hopefully I will be able to do it tomottow. I will get back to you with results. I have already addedd Accecc-control-allow-origin to the php side. many thanks

Comment: Hi vhtc, I tried & have difficulties. Here is the server code. header("Content-Type: application/json");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin :*");
header("Access-Control-Request-Method :GET, POST"); and in client I copied your code. But, in the console error is thrown. This is the error: OPTIONS http://192.168.1.102/server/server.ph…ed=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&_=1363329485854  
send 
p.extend.ajax 
callJSON 
(anonymous function) 
p.event.dispatch 
g.handle.h 
errorThrown I kept ajax in callJSON() function to repeat it 30 times. So, where is wrong? Plz help tnx.

Comment: Once contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8", the 'array' you are passing as parameter needs to be a json object.

data: {foo : 'bar'}

Comment: Nop I afraid. Since I am generating my array using javascript, I think making a json object becomes slightly tricky. I am now concern about that. Should I choose PhP instead?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
xhr=$.getJSON('http://192.168.1.102/server/server.php?callback=?',   
  {data:array}, function(res,status,xhr){
    alert(xhr.getAllResponseHeaders()); 
    // not getAllResponseHeader its only getResponseHeader
});
```

For `cross domain` use

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://192.168.1.102/server/server.php?callback=?',
  dataType: 'json',
  jsonpCallback: 'MyJSONPCallback', // specify the callback name if you're hard-coding it
  success: function(data){
    // we make a successful JSONP call!
  }
});
```

Refer this [jQuery getJSON works locally, but not cross domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849802/jquery-getjson-works-locally-but-not-cross-domain)

Docs For `getAllResponseHeaders`, `getResponseHeader` and `ajax` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: thanks Rohan, I have an Indexed array of number to send th the server. Is is okay if I send data:array. When I do so, the request header becomes full of undefined=&...server/server.php?callback=callback&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined. I guess my data should be in a form of key/value, so I did data:{1:123} and sent, but I never receive any reply.

Comment: The first code block is confusing: It uses `getAll...` but the comment says not to use it.