# what is the reason for Access-Control-Allow-Origin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, http, cross-domain

I've tried to understand HTTP base statements, because that is not working as I expected.

E.g. I've put `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` as http://www.example.com, and I tried to send POST requests from http://www.example2.com and it was with error like I expected.

It says `...request has been blocked by CORS policy`. 
But I was wonder when looked that actually that request was done on http://www.example.com and POST action was called.

Question then, why do we need that `protection`?

Comment: For a couple of good explanations, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9222822/why-do-browser-apis-restrict-cross-domain-requests/9223680#9223680 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228150/why-are-cross-domain-ajax-requests-labelled-as-a-security-risk/9228196#9228196

Comment: thanks for links. but things that I still can send all kinds of requests, but can't
handle response

Answer (score 0):

When a web-page is loaded into a browser, its HTML, CSS, Javascript is loaded, its session is being used. Some of the many potential problems:

1. The remote page inside the `iframe` might be a page where you are logged in (like your personal email account's web-page) and a spider could silently steal important data (like the content of your emails, including access to confidential areas, like bank account-related data, personal, private data, etc.)
2. Confidential CSS/Javascript could be stolen from trusted users. Example: you create some very good code in Javascript and CSS and only paid users can use their benefit. However, someone sends you a link which points to a page which loads your site silently as an iframe and extracts the CSS and Javascript goodies from there. Then the stealer will sell your product with a discount and you can work on new products and on a better security policy.
3. Your accounts could be hacked. A page where you have an active session could be loaded inside an `iframe` and then a spider could wreak havoc there, including, but by far not limited to changing your username/password and excluding you from your own account.
4. Malicious things could be done against others in your name.